# Equinumerous finite sets

Tags: combinatorics, functions

Let $A$ and $B$ be two finite sets and we have two functions $f: A\to B$ and $g: B \to A$ such that

- for any $a\in A$, $g(f(a))=a$
- for any $b\in B$, $f(g(b))=b$.

Then can I conclude that $A$ and $B$ must have the same cardinality?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. This is often used as the definition of two sets having the same cardinality (which works for infinite sets as well). If you really want, the first condition implies that $f$ is injective and the second one implies that $f$ is surjective.